# Why can't I use add?

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have a problem with and exercise in java.
I'm managin a logistics company I want to add a Booking into a BookingRegister.

```
 Booking booking = Booking.makebooking (trip,originCity,arrivalDate,merchandise,departureDate,kg);

       BookingRegister bookingRegister = getBookingRegister();

        bookingRegister.add(Prenotazione);
```

But i can't use  `add()` even if the BookingRegister is an ArrayList

```
public class BookingRegister {

    private List<Booking> BookingRegister = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: The `class BookingRegister` is not an `ArrayList`, it has a field `BookingRegister` of type `ArrayList<...>`. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic of classes and objects, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! I've done an Override of the add method to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

First, you should **not** make the `List` public. Instead, provide a method that takes a `Booking` and does something with it. That could be adding it to a `List`. Like,

```
public class BookingRegister {
    private List<Booking> register = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addBooking(Booking b) {
        register.add(b);
    }
}
```

Next, call that method. Like,

```
// This looks like a builder pattern. Why not new Booking?
Booking booking = Booking.makebooking (trip,
    originCity, arrivalDate, merchandise, departureDate, kg);

BookingRegister bookingRegister = getBookingRegister();
bookingRegister.addBooking(booking);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the List BookingRegister is `private`.
Make it `public`.

Another thing is, in line 3 you have used the class name instead of the variable name.
Changing it to `bookingRegister` would solve it...

Comment: This will not solve the problem.

Comment: Then check if the variable added `Prenotazione` is created or not...

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, give me some time to edit. I just noticed it and while changing it, one big comment just came onto my face.